# Forward packets using iptables

Tags: vpn, iptables, forward

I have two servers : server A and server B.
Another company has server C and ASA FW.

I have established an IPsec Tunnel between Server B and the ASA firewall on the remote peer.

Now I need to make server A to connect to server C through the tunnel I established using Server B .

Can this be done using iptables, what are the required rules?

- Note we are dealing here with only public ip addresses ( no NAT ).

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing any NAT anywhere in the chain, you will need to set up server A to route to the network that server C is on via server B, so that packets from server A to server C will pass through server B. Likewise, you will need to make sure that any packets from server C to server A are directed through the VPN tunnel to server B.

Since you are using IPsec, you will need to make sure that you have the proper phase 2 definitions set up.

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant network configuration for all 4 systems. Feel free to obfuscate IP addresses, but make sure they're identifiable between each other.